# Order a data frame only from a certain row index to a certain row index

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

Let's say we have a DF like this:

```
col1 col2 
A   1
A   5
A   3
A   16
B   5
B   4
B   3
C   7
C   2
```

I'm trying to order col2 but only for same values in col1. Better said, I want it to look like this:

```
 col1 col2 
    A   1
    A   3
    A   5
    A   16
    B   3
    B   4
    B   5
    C   2
    C   7
```

So order col2 only for A, B and C values, not order the entire col2 column

```
x <- function() {
    values<- unique(DF[, 1])

      for (i in values) {
        currentData <- which(DF$col1== i)

## what to do here ?

        data[order(data[, 2]), ]
      }

}
```

so in `CurrentData` I have indexes for col2 values for only As, Bs etc. But how do I order only those items in my entire DF data frame ? Is it somehow possible to tell the order function to do order only on certain row indexes of data frame ?

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Comment: Except when you try to enter data.frame the SO interface refuses to provide an accepted tag and instead substitutes '`dataframe`.

Comment: @BhargavRao Thinking you had posted a comment but failed to make the effort at doing the editing I tried and failed.  Apparently, somebody in SO control has not honored that community effort and instead has merged the tags. S/R had dataframes before Python existed, so pythonistas should not assume they own the term. So I think you are the one "not careful".

Comment: @42- this was discussed almost 2 years ago here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319590/one-frame-to-rule-them-all-how-to-handle-data-frame-dataframes-mistagging by R folks. Do post any of your issues on that meta post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ave` will group the data by the first element, and apply the named function to the second element for each group.  Here is an application of `ave` sorting within groups:

```
DF$col2 <- ave(DF$col2, DF$col1, FUN=sort)
DF
##   col1 col2
## 1    A    1
## 2    A    3
## 3    A    5
## 4    A   16
## 5    B    3
## 6    B    4
## 7    B    5
## 8    C    2
## 9    C    7
```

This will work even if the values in `col1` are not consecutive, leaving them in their original positions.

If that is not an important consideration, there are better ways to do this, such as the answer by @user314046.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed. Seeing as I'm new to R, I didn't know this function existed.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that

```
my_df[with(my_df, order(col1, col2)), ]
```

will do what you want - this just sorts the `dataframe` by `col1` and `col2`. If you don't want to order by `col1` a method is provided in the other answer.

Comment: @anada thx I was going to leave a comment but it was coming out unreadable. Probably this is a dup of something.

Comment: Nice, only thing to note is that this will also order col1.

Comment: @beginneR Often, such reordering so that each factor level is grouped in the data frame does not hurt any further analysis.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I agree with that. And I didn't mean that it will be grouped but reordered in the sense that if in col1, `B` and `A` were exchanged, the output would reorder it so that `A` comes first. But I agree that this will probably not hurt any further analysis.